# Passando o atributo de um elemento de lista como parâmetro de um método

Tags: dart

Há a possiblidade de passar o atributo de um elemento/objeto de uma lista como parâmetro de uma função e utilizá-lo para retornar os valores?

```
  static Future<List<dynamic>> filterElementsInList(
      {required String query, required String elementAttribute, required List<dynamic> list}) async {
    if (query.isEmpty) {
      return list;
    } else {
      return list.where((entity) {
        
        return entity.elementAttribute.contains(query);
      }).toList();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Não entendi exatamente o que você está tentando fazer. A sua dúvida é como utilizar uma string (como `elementAttribute` no seu exemplo) para acessar uma propriedade dinamicamente, é isso?

Comment: Exato. Imagine que o valor passado para o parâmetro `elementAttribute` é `name`.  Essa seria a propriedade buscada de fato no elemento.

Comment: Até onde eu entendo, é possível fazer isso utilizando `reflect` em Dart, mas o mesmo não é possível no Flutter (imagino que seja para esse fim que você está utilizando). Descreva mais a situação por favor, dependendo do caso você poderá utilizar `reflect`, ou então terá que implementar uma interface `ToMap` nos objetos que for utilizar nessa função, ou talvez nem seja necessário/viável fazer dessa maneira.

Comment: Será utilizado em uma aplicação Flutter, entretanto estou colocando este código em uma biblioteca separada `package` dart puro. Esta é a razão de querer receber a propriedade como parâmetro e acessá-la dinamicamente no objeto uma vez que não sei de antemão que parâmetros o objeto/elemento da lista terá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você está pedindo não será possível.

Mesmo que você crie o código numa lib separada em Dart puro, essa lib terá que ser compilada no projeto do Flutter. Os *runtimes* de Dart script e Flutter são diferentes, um é convertido para JavaScript e executado no NodeJS, e o outro é convertido para código nativo para Android ou iPhone, como resultado existe alguns recursos que são exclusivos para determinados *runtimes*, e o `reflect` é um deles.

O que você pode fazer dará mais trabalho, mas é algo que já esperados dos projetos em Dart: crie os métodos `toJSON` nas suas classes para transforma-las num `Map<String, dynamic>`, tal método é um padrão utilizado para converter seus objetos em uma string no formato *JSON*.

**Exemplo**

Aqui vou aproveitar para declarar uma classe abstrata com esse método para poder utilizar esse contrato depois:

```dart
abstract class JsonSerializable {
  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON();
}

class User implements JsonSerializable {
  String name;
  String email;
  User({ required this.name, required this.email });

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() {
    return {'name': name, 'email': email};
  }
}
```

Tendo esse método implementado, podemos converter o objeto numa instância de `Map` e acessar as propriedades a partir de uma string.

Vou utilizar um *generic* na função para tornar a tipagem segura:

```dart
List<T> filterElementsInList<T extends JsonSerializable>({
  required String query,
  required String elementAttribute,
  required List<T> list,
}) {
  if (query.isEmpty) return list;
  return list.where((entity) => entity.toJSON()[elementAttribute].contains(query)).toList();
}
```

A utilização é como você já espera:

```dart
final users = [
  User(name: 'Darcey', email: 'dtremoulet0@craigslist.org'),
  User(name: 'Gisella', email: 'gwagnerin1@hatena.ne.jp'),
  User(name: 'Eliot', email: 'eschanke2@facebook.com'),
  User(name: 'Montgomery', email: 'mdavidwitz3@nsw.gov.au'),
  User(name: 'Drucill', email: 'dshowers4@github.com'),
];

final filtered = filterElementsInList(query: 'Eliot', elementAttribute: 'name', list: users);
print(filtered[0].email);
```

---

**Mas e a implementação em Dart?**

`reflect` permite que você acesse dinamicamente as propriedades de um objeto sem precisar implementar manualmente métodos auxiliares. Mas essa abordagem requer entendimento das abstrações que a linguagem aplica no seu código, e é fácil cair em *edge case*. Leia mais em [mirrors](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html).

**Exemplo**

```dart
List<T> filterElementsInList<T extends Object>({
  required String query,
  required String elementAttribute,
  required List<T> list,
}) {
  if (query.isEmpty) return list;
  return list.where((entity) => reflect(entity).getField(Symbol(elementAttribute)).reflectee.contains(query)).toList();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pele detalhamento da resposta! Como minhas classes já implementam o to/fromMap será mais fácil adotar esta solução.